# Valor de variable para columna

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Estoy tratando de sacar el valor de la línea 0 que me genera un sensor en el archivo sensor1.txt y poder utilizar ese valor str como nombre de una columna para Pandas. No lo consigo y no sé si es posible.

La variable linea adquiere el valor bien, si lo imprimo lo veo. new_columns es cuando me falla. Quiero que el valor linea se cambie a test.

```
with open("sensor1.txt") as f:
    linea = f.readlines()[0]

new_columns = {linea : 'test'}
df.rename(columns = new_columns, inplace=True)
df.columns
```

Un saludo y gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo tengo solucionado. El problema es que la variable línea almacenaba también un salto de línea. Añadiendo al final [:-1] borro el salto de línea y lo reconoce bien.

```
with open("sensor.txt") as f:
    linea = f.readlines()[0][:-1] 

new_columns = {linea : 'test'}
df.rename(columns = new_columns, inplace=True)
df.columns
```